# Correct way to cite paper that is published as part of a book

Tags: citations, citation-style

I'm working on the last parts of my diploma in computer engineering. Right now i'm working over my bibliography. And i'm not quite sure what's the best way to include a citation.

Both refer to the same paper, the first one is a lot more detailed but it's not possible to view the whole paper online, since a few pages are being left out. 
The second one only refers to the paper, not including any publisher etc.

```
@inproceedings{booth2009,
author = {Booth, Danielle and Jansen, Bernard J},
booktitle = {Handbook of Research on Web Log Analysis},
title = {A Review of Methodologies for Analyzing Websites},
year = {2009},
pages = {143-164},
publisher = {IGI Global},
doi = {10.4018/978-1-59904-974-8}
}
```

or

```
@article{booth2009,
title={A Review of Methodologies for Analyzing Websites},
author={Booth, Danielle and Jansen, Bernard J},
year={2009}
}
```

Which one should I use?

Comment: _which one would you use?_ — I would use the first, but with the correct author field "author = {Booth, Danielle}",  additional fields "chapter = {8}" and "editor = {Bernard J. Jansen and Amanda Spink and Isak Taska}", and an en-dash (--) instead of a hyphen (-) between the page numbers.  The fact that the paper is not available online is utterly irrelevant.

Comment: @JeffE: *The fact that the paper is not available online is utterly irrelevant.* – Well, one could argue that this makes it **even more important** to provide full bibliographical data to allow the reader to finde the full paper.

Comment: Sidenote: Your citation seems to be `@inbook`, not `@inproceedings`, though this makes no difference in most citation styles.

Comment: thanks for the replies. the paper itself references jansen as co-author so i guess ill have to include him right? Never thought about the editor field thanks for that! The thing is the paper is accessible online just not through the book, thats why i was wondering if it wouldnt be better to use the short citation. just beginning to review all of my citations, most of them are provided by ieee, google scholar etc but seem to be rather inaccurate.

Comment: _the paper itself references jansen as co-author_ — So it does!  Your original author field is correct; my apologies. See also: [Muprhy's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muphry%27s_law).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The references are there for your readers to be able to hunt down the reference, be it to check what you say or to follow a different thread of research. For their sake, do find out as complete bibliographic data as you can, and add them to the citation.